# Creating object from a file and store them into an arraylist. file is like (tools = 2000; fixTools=500 and etc )

Tags: arrays, string, object, arraylist, buffer

```java
BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\eclipse-workspace\\MissionMars\\src\\phase-2"));
String line;

ArrayList <Items> point = new ArrayList<Items>();
while((line=bin.readLine())  != null  ) 
{
    String [] value = line.split(" = ");
    String x=value[0];  
    int y=Integer.parseInt(value[1]);

    Items obj1 = new Items(x,y);

    obj1.setName(x);
    obj1.setWeight(y);

    point.add(obj1);
}

System.out.println(point);
```

My program shows:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 5000".

Comment: maybe remove spaces first and then split by "=" ?

Answer (score 0):

As a general practice, you should be a bit more defensive in code that processes input. In this particular case, there's a leading space in the number string that you've shown in the exception. You can solve that with something like:

```java
...
int y = Integer.parseInt(value[1].trim());
...
```

That will handle leading and trailing spaces, but the program will still throw an exception if the number is not well-formatted. I would suggest putting the parsing in a try/catch block where you set reasonable or meaningful default values when there's an exception.

Comment: yeah that helped . but atlast i override the toString method which printed my arralist of objects.